# Documents Checkedout even after calling file.checkin or publish- system account

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

am facing an issue while check-in and publish the document attached for the  splist item programmatically.
for my  requirement, there exists an field, projcode, and for this projcode, there are multiple documents/items associated with it.when i do an checkin the documents, for this projcode associated items, i have to call file.checkin/ publish using c# , in an item event receiver.

but strangely, am unable to  checkin-publish all the docs, successfully, instead , some getting the documents successfully checked-in  soem docs are checkout by system account.

[image: document-not-checked-in-not-published]

[image: code-checkin-publish]

[image: require-docs-checkedout]

[image: create-major-minor-versions1]